# Is it possible to adjust a font's vertical scaling using CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, scaling, embedded-fonts

I am using an embedded font for the top navigational elements on a site
`Helvetica65` and at `16px` it is the perfect WIDTH but I need it to be
about `90%` of it's current height.

In Photoshop, the solution is simple - adjust the vertical scaling.

Is there a way to do essentially the same thing using CSS? And if so, how
well is it supported?

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jd5Y7/) of the basic nav coding.

Comment: Can we see your code, or can you set us a jsfiddle?

Comment: Just posted it in the edit to my original post.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

The [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property can be used to scale text.
It's for blocks, so you'll need to also add `display: inline-block` in order to use it on HTML elements like **<a>**, **<span>**, **<em>**, **<kbd>**, etc.

```css
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

a.vertical-scaling {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(1, 1.5);
  /* Safari and Chrome */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 1.5);
  /* Firefox */
  -moz-transform: scale(1, 1.5);
  /* IE 9+ */
  -ms-transform: scale(1, 1.5);
  /* Opera */
  -o-transform: scale(1, 1.5);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a class="vertical-scaling" href="/">HOME</a></li>
  <li><a href="/expert-witness">EXPERT WITNESS<a/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have applied the scale transform to a heading which makes it wider and not as tall. This means the text now starts to the left of the rest of the text on the page. I have added margin to the left to push it back into line. Is there anyway to calculate this difference with transform?

Comment: @RouthMedia you are looking for `transform-origin`. probably `transform-origin: top left;`

Comment: It should be noted that this approach is based on scaling the whole block - therefore will NOT work for `display: inline;` - the element must be block-like (block, table, inline block, ... ).