# Changing Width of Font Awesome Icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to adjust the scaling and width of an icon.  I'm specifically trying to make the icon

`<i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>`

wider, but not taller.

I'm not trying to make it `fa-2x` or `fa-3x`. I'm trying to scale it so that the width is, say 150%, while the height is still 100%.

Comment: For font awesome you must use font-size to adjust is size

Comment: font-size uses fixed scaling. I'm trying to scale width independently of height.

Comment: Maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16447826/107244

Comment: Font Awesome is a font, and the icons are actually text, so your question should be can I stretch text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351013/css-can-i-stretch-text

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Really easy using scale

```
.fa { transform: scale(1.5,1); }
```

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping that I wouldn't have to use transforms, but since it's a font, I guess I have to.  Thank you.

Comment: great, thanks.
should use cross browser prefix too?
`-webkit-transform: scale(1.5,1);
-moz-transform:    scale(1.5,1);
-ms-transform:     scale(1.5,1);
-o-transform:      scale(1.5,1);
transform:         scale(1.5,1);`

Comment: That worked like a charm. Although i used it to increase height of the font awesome icon but still it gave me an idea.

Comment: This will distorted the icons. using font-size to upper div/elements work fine for me.

Comment: @Amitkumar - yes, of course it will. However, the OP asked `I'm specifically trying to make the icon wider, but not taller.` which is why this is the correct answer to the asked question.

Answer (score 5):

This answer only works when you are trying to adjust the icons in the list. But I am posting this because I guess some people visiting this page is in this situation.

If you are so applying "fa-fw" class to icons solves the problems.

Example from docs.

```
<div style="font-size: 2rem;">
  <div><i class="fas fa-skating fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Skating</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-skiing fa-fw" style="background:SkyBlue"></i> Skiing</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-skiing-nordic fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Nordic Skiing</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-snowboarding fa-fw" style="background:SkyBlue"></i> Snowboarding</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-snowplow fa-fw" style="background:DodgerBlue"></i> Snowplow</div>
</div>
```

Docs
https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons

Answer (score 4):

At first I was also worried that how to change the size of icons of font awesome, I tried lots of method even I tried to add some classes that individually increase or
decrease the size of icon.. but nothing worked as it supposed to .. but then I found
some classes which was already defined by font awesome to play with size of icons .and
here are the list of some classes..

```
<i class="fas fa-home fa-xs">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-sm">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-lg">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-2x">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-3x">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-4x">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-5x">
<i class="fas fa-home fa-6x">
```

now enjoy with your icon ..goodluck