# How to scale Font Awesome 5 icon only on x-axis without distortion

Tags: html, css, svg, scale, font-awesome-5

I have the following `grid` layout.

```html
<div class="container">
  <i class="far fa-circle left"></i>  <!--left col-->
  <i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right arrow"></i>  <!--mid col-->
  <i class="fas fa-circle right"></i>  <!--right col-->
</div>
```

In all 3 columns I show icons. I want to scale up the icon, in the middle, only on x-axis, without distortion. I have tried to apply `transform: scale(x,y)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564793/changing-width-of-font-awesome-icons) as shown below.

```css
.container {
  width: 10em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 1fr;
}

.arrow {
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: 250%;
  transform: scale(2, 1); /*<-- scaling*/
}

.left {
  font-size: 250%;
  justify-self: end;
}

.right {
  font-size: 250%;
  justify-self: start;
}
```

However, it distorts the icon as can be seen below.

[image]

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/sayan751/pen/51f9f7cbe729783e8f95bcae240eca11).

Is there any CSS-based solution for this?  Alternatively, a solution is also welcomed that stretches the icon, such that it fills up the x-axis of the middle column. Actually, that is even better :)

Comment: Use `transform: scale(2, 2);`instead of `transform: scale(2, 1);`

Comment: By definition, scaling on one axis only will result in distortion. What you ask is impossible without creating a new version of the icon.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Yup, realize that now. I think that I will close this question.